# Installing old versions of Ruby and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, rvm

My system is currently running Ruby v2.1.2p95, Rails v4.1.4 and RVM 1.25.28.

I have a project that is running on Rails 3.0.9 and was wondering what the best approach to installing older versions of Ruby/Rails would be? Do I need to install an old version of Ruby to use Rails 3.0.9? Provided below is the gemfile for this old project.

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.9'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'active_link_to'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 2.2.2'
gem 'annotate'
gem 'aws-s3'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'devise'
gem 'easy_roles'
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'impressionist'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'koala'
# gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.2.6'
gem "oa-oauth", :require => "omniauth/oauth"
gem 'paperclip', '~> 2.3'
# gem 'twitter'
# gem 'twitter-text'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development, :test do
  gem 'mysql2'
end
```

Comment: `bundle` will install rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two files for the project: A file called `.ruby-version` which should have `2.1.2` in it, and a file called `.ruby-gemset` which should have the name of the project in it.

`cd` into the directory, and RVM will setup an environment where you can just run `bundle` and have the old version of Rails install without conflicting with your other versions you may use.

This will also allow you to bump down the Ruby version if you need to.

Comment: Hey @jeremywoetink, thanks for the answer. Are these files created by command-line or manually? When you mention name of the project, do you mean the name of the github repository or directory name? Thanks.

Comment: You just create these files manually in your text editor. Or if you want to use the command line `touch .ruby-version` and `touch .ruby-gemset`. The gemset can be called anything you like. I only say project name because it helps with organization.

Comment: you can also specify `ruby '2.1.2'` in your Gemfile.